# Set value of $scope variable from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set a value to a variable in $scope from jQuery function as below code. Everything is good but the new value is reflecting in UI.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";

    $('#sample').click(function(e){
        $scope.carname = "Audi";
    });
});
```

Here is my complete program: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDD7P0CSN4C8)

I will be glad if someone help me with this.

Comment: why not use `ng-click` handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make your code work, you need to run `$scope.$digest()` after you assign `$scope.carname = "Audi";`

Like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";

    $('#sample').click(function(e){
        $scope.carname = "Audi";
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

Here's a w3schools link to the program: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDD8FF21E1QB)

As mentioned in the comments below, you can also use `$scope.$apply()` like the following:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Volvo";

    $('#sample').click(function(e){
        $scope.$apply( function() {
            $scope.carname = "Audi";
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a w3schools link to the program: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDD8IAYMAXK6)

You can read more about the use cases for `$scope.$digest()` and `$scope.$apply()` in the following links:

- [Understanding Angular's $apply() and $digest()](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)
- [AngularJS $watch(), $digest(), and $apply()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

**Note:** As mentioned in many other comments & some answers, Angular does provide a built-in method to listen for a `click` event, called `ng-click`. Here is the documentation for it: [AngularJS: ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: better to call $scope.$apply() I'd say (https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: Please not only answer his question, but defy that he uses the `.click` handler instead of `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS provides `ng-click` directive to handle click event.Just add `ng-click=function_name()` as an attribute in your HTML element.The `ng-click` directive tells AngularJS what to do when an HTML element is clicked.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        console.log('clicked');
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why aren't you using the standard `ng-click` to catch the click event. Please explain if you have a specific reason for that. But if you still want to follow the Jquery way, you should invoke angular digest cycles, as soon as you change the value. Use `$scope.$apply()`